# pdfReader throws System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

```
 private void highlightPDFAnnotation(string outputFile, int pageno, string[] splitText)
{
    try
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(outputFile));
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
            {
                myLocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new myLocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageno, strategy);
                for (int i = 0; i < splitText.Length; i++)
                {
                    List<iTextSharp.text.Rectangle> MatchesFound = strategy.GetTextLocations(splitText[i].Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                    foreach (Rectangle rect in MatchesFound)
                    {
                        float[] quad = { rect.Left - 3.0f, rect.Bottom, rect.Right, rect.Bottom, rect.Left - 3.0f, rect.Top + 1.0f, rect.Right, rect.Top + 1.0f };
                        //Create our hightlight
                        PdfAnnotation highlight = PdfAnnotation.CreateMarkup(stamper.Writer, rect, null, PdfAnnotation.MARKUP_HIGHLIGHT, quad);
                        //Set the color
                        highlight.Color = BaseColor.YELLOW;

                        PdfAppearance appearance = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(stamper.Writer, rect.Width, rect.Height);
                        PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
                        state.BlendMode = new PdfName("Multiply");
                        appearance.SetGState(state);
                        appearance.Rectangle(0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height);
                        appearance.SetColorFill(BaseColor.YELLOW);
                        appearance.Fill();

                        highlight.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, appearance);

                        //Add the annotation
                        stamper.AddAnnotation(highlight, pageno);                            

                        highlight.Clear();

                    }
                }
                stamper.Close();
                stamper.Dispose();

            }
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();


        }
        reader.Close();

        reader = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

After fourth attempt it throws **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** error.

**Stacktrace :**

> at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs.ReadPages()
>   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs..ctor(PdfReader reader)
>   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.ReadPages()
>   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.ReadPdf()
>   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(Byte[] pdfIn, Byte[]
>   ownerPassword)    at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(Byte[] pdfIn)
>   at bottom.highlightPDFAnnotation(String outputFile, Int32 pageno,
>   String[] splitText)

Comment: At which line of code it throws this ?

Comment: PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(outputFile));

Comment: Check the value for `outputFile` variable and make sure it is accessible at the specified location.

Comment: this line does not throw any error. "System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(outputFile)".   new PdfReader( only throws error

Comment: Three times i can highlight the pdf. It throws error after 4th attempting.

Comment: Its tricky. Try putting a `for` loop with that one line of code and loop for 5-10 times and check if its working or not. Also, you might want to check on the official site for such an issue. It could possibly be a bug.

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(outputFile));           
            reader.Close();}
            reader = null;  It's working.

Comment: So I guess the code seems fine if its functioning properly in the loop. You said that you did four attempts. Any chance that it might be due to the variation in attempts such as time gap between attempts or some kind of manipulation performed or some other logic executed between the attempts that could somehow affect the file.

Comment: If you try again after such an exeption with the same input file, does the exception occur again?

Comment: Kindly check my updated code in the question. It does not throws any error when i comment  this line " stamper.AddAnnotation(highlight, pageno);"          After adding annotation only it throws error

Comment: @mkl, yes, I'm over writing the same file.

Comment: Please use different file names and try again. If the issue occurs then, too, please share the PDF that cannot be loaded anymore for analysis.

Comment: In other two pdf files, i highlighting the text 4 times and removed the higlighted text, it throws nullreferenceexception. Shall i provide other two pdf files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I get the bytes from this line "byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(highLightFile);" When passing the bytes to this line "PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);". It throws null value exception.

Comment: @mkl, i will create new file and swap them at the end.  File.Copy(highLightFile, outputFile,true);
            File.Delete(highLightFile); is it correct?

Comment: It's working fine. Thank you for all your support.